# How to delete a line having two patterns in two positions in a unix file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file like this.

```
aabbccde
aaeeffcc
aaffccdf
affdfdfc
```

I want to check if the 2nd position = a and the 7th position = d, that line should be deleted.

final output should be.

```
aaeeffcc
affdfdfc
```

I was trying from sed , but i can only check for 1 position at a time.

```
sed  '/^.\{1\}a/d' f1.dat > f2.dat
```

This deletes all lines which is having "a" in 2nd position of f1 file and create a new f2 file.

How can i delete the line by checking both conditions. position 2 = "a" and position 7 = "d"

Comment: `sed '/^.a....d/d'`

Comment: Or use `grep -v '^.a....d'`

Comment: Thank you, This saved almost 5 hours of my searching. Appreciate a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'substr($0,2,1)=="a" && substr($0,7,1)=="d"{next} 1' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:***

```
awk '!/^.a....d/ '  Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13,
All solutions are working. Great help